# PHP - Parameters default values

Tags: php, parameters, default

I have a function with multiple parameters.
Sometimes the user may need to specify, say, the first, second, and fourth, but not the third.
In JavaScript we can do that easily using an anonymous object as a single parameter for the whole function :

```
function foo(args) {
    if(args.arg0 != null) alert(args.arg0);
    if(args.arg1 != null) alert(args.arg2);
    if(args.arg2 != null) alert(args.arg1);
}

foo({
   arg0: 'foo',
   arg2: 10
});
```

If i want to do that in PHP, i can use an associative array to play the same role as this anonymous objects "args" in the function above :

```
foo(array(
   'arg0' => 'foo',
   'arg2' => 10
));
```

Which would not be possible using multiple parameters as one may not write :

```
foo('foo', , 10);
```

For some reason i find using arrays dirty for that, and wonder if there isn't a "cleaner" way.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: using an array is already a clean way to do so.

Comment: This is probably what i'm gonna have to do, but i wanted to make sure there isn't a better way

Comment: An array is a clean way to do this, CakePHP uses them a lot for things like options. Ex. http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/AJAX.html#methods. As an you could instead overload the methods.

Comment: Just use `foo('foo', null, 10);`

Comment: If i use `foo('foo', null, 10);` but the default value of the second parameter is, say, array(), will it be null or array() ?

Comment: Thanks ! So this is not what i'm looking for. I suppose i'll stick with arrays. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Agreed, an array is definitely considered best practice in this case. Without a doubt it is the right way to go.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with other commenters that say an array is a good solution. However, if you still want a different way to handle this check [func_get_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

Comment: Yep thanks, but using this i have no way to identify which parameter a value represents.

Comment: This is not a good solution. The only time func_get_args is the right thing to do is if you're going to pass an unknown number of objects or values to be processed in the same way.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. My "solution" will not address the problem (would it make sense to delete this answer?)